# OpenLayers shows white tiles on iPad

Tags: cocoa-touch, memory, uiwebview, openlayers

I'm experiencing some issues to do with OpenLayers in an UIWebView on the iPad. It's offline tile based layer loading locally from the users documents directory. Some tiles appear white and do not change until I change zoom levels, or scroll them far off the screen. However, this doesn't appear to be an issue that setting the number of retries will solve as I changed the missing tile color to red and it still appears white.

I'm wondering if the iPad is giving up on rendering the tiles due to memory constraints?

Answer (score 1):

Please try this anyway and tell us if you still have the problem.

```
OpenLayers.IMAGE_RELOAD_ATTEMPTS = 3;
```

Comment: Have tested this with 3, 5 and higher values. It would seem that it passes this case - the images do appear if you pinch out (so that the higher layer appears) and then pinch back in.

Comment: Strange, i'm not having these issues at all. You are running the latest 2.11?

Comment: I think so, I'm using it with output from gdal2tiles on large images (about 30k x 30k) It's touch only on the iPad using "OpenLayers.Control.TouchNavigation" and the "OpenLayers.Layer.TMS" layer

Answer (score 0):

I've just solved this issue, it seems that `src` is never released with the standard `Image.clear()` method, it took me some times and tweak to get it work.

Comment: Could you just post those further details here?  Thanks.

Comment: Would really like the answer here :) It's still an issue for me. (and seemingly others)

Comment: Also, you don't have any contact information in your profile. So I can't get in touch with you about it.